# using R segmented package with lognormal errors

Tags: r, regression, piecewise

My model is:

```
y = f(x) exp(E)  where E~N(0,sig^2)
```

> where f(x) = piece-wise linear model (ax + bI(x-d)(x-d))
>    (a and b are parameters, d = breakpoint, I = indicator function)

s.t

```
log (y) = log(f(x)) + E
```

I have coded:

```
lin.mod <- lm(y~x  - 1,data=data)
startingVals <- 10000
seg.mod <- segmented(lin.mod, intercp=F, seg.Z = ~x, psi=startingVals)
```

Everything runs just fine but this is fitting the model assuming gaussian errors (y = f(x) + E), not lognormal errors.

How do I specify the appropriate linear model to pass to segmented?

Now I have coded this problem myself looping through a vector of breakpoints and optimizing the loglikelihood given he breakpoint but it takes a while (I have a fine grid).

I'd like to be able to use segmented to speed things up, but it is unclear how i would do this.
Thanks

Comment: The answer is: You can't, it is not set up to fit this kind of error structure.

Answer (score 0):

Firth (1988, JRSSB p. 266-268) discusses similarities between log Normal and Gamma distribution. Thus, a first (approximate) approach could be to use a GLM with Gamma family and identity link. segmented works with GLMs.

```
library(segmented)
o<-glm(y~x, family=Gamma(link="identity"))
os<-segmented(o, ~x) #for 1 breakpoint the starting value for psi could be omitted
```

When fitting 'o', it could help to provide starting values. For instance,

```
beta0<-coef(lm(log(y)~x))
glm(y~x, family=Gamma(link="identity"), start=beta0)
```